# SQL INSERT but increment ID if exist without having to do separate SELECT query

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, sql-insert

I have a table with Primary Key on two columns: `ID` (Users ID) and `SQ` (Sequence, this starts at 1 and increments +1 for each `ID`). A user should not have multiple instances of the same sequence #. Here is how the table looks:

```
ID      SQ    Code
------  --    ----
123456  1     123
654321  1     369
123456  2     234
```

I am trying to insert a value in column `Code` but before I do that I need to check if a specific user already has that code and if so, receive the Sequence #.

Currently, I run:

```
# CodeExists is 1 if user has code already. 0 otherwise
# Max_SQ gives the maximum SQ that exists for this user
cursor.execute("SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN Code = ? THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'CodeExists', MAX(SQ) AS 'Max_SQ' FROM TABLENAME WHERE ID = ? GROUP BY ID", Code, User_PID)
data = cursor.fetchone()
if data is None: # This user does not have any codes, SQ starts at 1
    SQ = 1
else:
    CodeExists, SQ = data # Unpack query values
    if int(CodeExists) == 1: # User already has the code we are trying to insert, skip
        continue
    else:
        SQ = int(SQ) + 1 # Increment SQ
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO TABLENAME (ID,SQ,Code) VALUES(?,?,?)", User_PID, SQ, Code)
cursor.commit()
```

Examples:

- Trying to insert Code=123 for User=123456, should not insert. This user has code 123 already.
- Trying to insert Code=123 for User=654321, should insert with SQ=2
- Trying to insert Code=123 for User=999999, should insert with SQ=1

Given a Code # and User ID, is there a way to combine this into a single INSERT query?

Comment: Is there a unique constraint for the combination of the columns ID and Code?

Comment: @forpas Its not constrained in table definition but an ID should not have the same code multiple times.

Comment: No, there is no such built-in feature. You would likely be better off determining the value at run time with `ROW_NUMBER`.

Comment: Agree with @ThomA. There's not really a super clean way to do what you want here. Instead of trying to increment the seq of every individual users, I'd just have a global identity on the table, and keep track of which one was more recently inserted that way. Then, if you need to get the codes sorted 1 thru n for your app, query the data like `select row_number() over (partition by UserID order by GlobalSeq)`

Comment: are you using transactions, locking, or a clustered index on your table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a CTE to store the the `ID` and `Code` of the new row.
Then do a `LEFT` join of the CTE to the table and aggregate to get the max `SQ` for that `ID` and increase it by 1.
In the `HAVING` clause set the condition that if there is already a row in the table where the Code is the same as the one in the CTE then the query should not return any row to be inserted.

This is the query:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT * FROM (VALUES (123456, 123))t (ID, Code))
INSERT INTO tablename (ID, SQ, Code)
SELECT c.ID,
       COALESCE(MAX(t.SQ), 0) + 1,
       c.Code
FROM cte c LEFT JOIN tablename t
ON t.ID = c.ID 
GROUP BY c.ID, c.Code
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN c.Code = t.Code THEN 1 END) IS NULL;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ptxng-T8).

Answer (score 1):

in MysQL  you can do it like this

```
CREATE TABLE TABLENAME
    (`ID` int, `SQ` int, `Code` int)
;
    
INSERT INTO TABLENAME
    (`ID`, `SQ`, `Code`)
VALUES
    (123456, 1, 123),
    (654321, 1, 369),
    (123456, 2, 234)
;
```

```
INSERT INTO TABLENAME (ID,SQ,Code) 
SELECT 1223344,( SELECT COALESCE(MAX(SQ),0) +1 FROM TABLENAME  WHERE ID =  1223344) ,666 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM TABLENAME  WHERE ID =  1223344 AND Code = 666)
```

> ```
> Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
INSERT INTO TABLENAME (ID,SQ,Code) 
SELECT 123456,( SELECT COALESCE(MAX(SQ),0) +1 FROM TABLENAME  WHERE ID =  123456) ,666 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM TABLENAME  WHERE ID =  123456 AND Code = 666)
```

> ```
> Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
INSERT INTO TABLENAME (ID,SQ,Code) 
SELECT 1223344,( SELECT COALESCE(MAX(SQ),0) +1 FROM TABLENAME  WHERE ID =  1223344) ,666 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM TABLENAME  WHERE ID =  1223344 AND Code = 666)
```

> ```
> Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME
```

| ID | SQ | Code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 1 | 123 |
| 654321 | 1 | 369 |
| 123456 | 2 | 234 |
| 1223344 | 1 | 666 |
| 123456 | 3 | 666 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/uE60sSmy)